# Highcharts. How to update x and y of the dataLabel?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to update x and y dataLabel parameters of the specific point. Is it possible to do in highcharts?

I tried to update point like this. But this didn't work as I expected.

```
chart.series[0].points[1].update({
    dataLabels: {x: 20, y: -20}
});
```

Here is jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/chermio/0973fcwb/1/

Comment: In pie chart it is possible to update dataLabels.distance option: https://jsfiddle.net/0973fcwb/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comment

In pie chart it is possible to update dataLabels.distance option:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance

```
function(chart) {    
    chart.series[0].points[1].update({
        dataLabels: {distance: -10}
    });
  }
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/0973fcwb/4/